# Conditioned probability of X by itself

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$. I want to find the density of $X | X>4$. I don't understand if $X | X>4$ is still a random variable. I want to generate observations from $X|X>4$ by rejection method and I think this is a good start to find repartition of $X|X>4$ but I don't know how to. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about your last sentence about "repartition". It looks like you just need to naturally generate $X$ and accept only if $X > 4$ for a truncated distribution like this.

Comment: @BGM but... $X|X>4$ is a random variable or not?

Comment: Yes it is still a random variable. A conditional probability measure is still a probability measure and possess every properties that an ordinary probability measure has. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition
From this definition, each random variable has associated with a probability triple. You may think that $X|X>4$ differ from $X$ by the probability measure only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$X \mid X>4$" is a controversial notation for something which has a  a [conditional probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution), and in this particular case it has a [truncated distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution).

The reason the notation is controversial is that if the probability space underlying the random variable $X$ is $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ then conditioning changes the space.  So statements like $\mathbb E[X \mid X>4]$ should not be read as $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ operating on $X \mid X>4$, but as $\mathbb E[\cdot\mid X>4]$ operating on $X$. Similarly with the conditional cumulative distribution function $F(x \mid X>4) = \mathbb P(X\le x \mid X>4)$ and the conditional density $f(x \mid X>4)$.

You could use rejection sampling to approximate the conditional distribution, but since here $\mathbb P(X>4)=e^{-4} \approx 0.0183$ you will find yourself rejecting over $98\%$ of the sample.  There are better ways here.

One is to find the conditional CDF and density.

Clearly  $\mathbb P(X\le x \mid X>4)=0$ for $x \le 4$, while for $x>4$ you can say $\mathbb P(X\le x \mid X>4)=1- \mathbb P(X\gt x \mid X>4) = 1 - \frac{\mathbb P(X\gt x )}{\mathbb P(X\gt 4 )} = 1-\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-4}} = 1-e^{-(x-4)}$ giving a conditional density of $f(x \mid X>4)=e^{-(x-4)}$ when $x>4$.

You could then invert the conditional CDF to get the conditional quantile function $4-\log(1-p)$,  and then create a sample by applying this to a sample of $p$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$.

In this particular case, you could alternatively use the [memorylessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) property of the exponential distribution and simply say that if $X$ has an exponential distribution then $X+4$ has the same distribution as the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X>4$. So you can generate a sample of your original $X$ and simply add $4$ to each value.